# Agregar resultado de un State dentro de otro State aiudaa!

Tags: reactjs, typescript

buenas tardes, mi problema es el siguiente:

- tengo una array de direcciones de empresas, las cuales como objeto tienen, label y location.

si una empresa no tiene esta info hay que cargarla.
mi problema viene aqui.
``const handleChangeAddCompanyInfo = (event: React.ChangeEvent) => {
const { name, value } = event.target;

```
        setCompany(...company, (setAddCompany({...addCompany, [name] : value})))
};``
```

debo agregar label y location al array de companies manejados por el state company y setcompany.
en otras palabras hacer un push a ese array pero no logro hacerlo el error que me arroja es
"un argumento de difusion debe tener un tipo tupla..."

les agradezco la ayuda.

````
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { Avatar, Box, Container, FormControl, Stack, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { MuiChipsInput, MuiChipsInputChip } from "mui-chips-input";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Dialog from "@mui/material/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@mui/material/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@mui/material/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@mui/material/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@mui/material/DialogTitle";

interface Client {
    Avatar: string;
    Name: string;
    LastName: string;
    Email: string;
    Phone: number;
    Company: Object
}

type Company = {
    label?: string;
    location?: string;
};

const companies = [
    { label: "Valor Digital 1", location: "calle Siempre viva 742" },
    { label: "Valor Digital 2", location: "calle Siempre viva 742" },
    { label: "Valor Digital 3", location: "calle Siempre viva 742" },
    { label: "Valor Digital 4", location: "calle Siempre viva 742" },
    { label: "Valor Digital 5", location: "calle Siempre viva 742" },
    { label: "Valor Digital 6", location: "calle Siempre viva 742" },
    { label: "Valor Digital 7", location: "calle Siempre viva 742" },
];
const CreateUser = () => {
    //manejador de array empresas
    const [company, setCompany] = useState(companies);

    //manejador de array para agregar clientes nuevos, form completo
    const [newClient, setNewClient] = useState(Array<Client>);

    //manejador del CHip telefonos
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState<MuiChipsInputChip[]>([]);

    //manejador de array para empresas de clientes
    const [addCompany, setAddCompany] = useState<Company | null>(null);
   // manejador de estado para 

    const [value1, setValue1] = useState<Company | null>(null);
  
    

    const handleSubmit = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
    };

    const handleSubmitCompanyInfo = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setCompany(company)
        console.log("deberia hacerlo")
        

        

    };

    const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setNewClient({ ...newClient, [name]: value });
    };

    //handlechange del MuiChipsInput
    const handleChange2 = (newValue: MuiChipsInputChip[]) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };

    const handleChangeAddCompanyInfo = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
            
            setCompany(...company, (setAddCompany({...addCompany, [name] : value})))
    };

    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
    };
    

    return (
        <>
            <Typography sx={{ textAlign: "center" }} variant="h5" color="primary" mt={4}>
                Create New User
            </Typography>
            <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} sx={{ width: "500px" }}>
                <Container maxWidth="lg">
                    <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
                        <Avatar alt="New User" src="https://i.pravatar.cc/350?u=pablo_Gonzalez5" />
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            required
                            id="outlined-required"
                            label="Name"
                            name="Name"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            required
                            id="outlined-textarea"
                            label="LastName"
                            multiline
                            name="LastName"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            margin="dense"
                            required
                            id="outlined-textarea"
                            label="email"
                            multiline
                            name="email"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />

                        <MuiChipsInput value={value} onChange={handleChange2} size="medium" hideClearAll />

                        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                            <Autocomplete
                                sx={{ width: "300px" }}
                                options={companies}
                                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="companies" />}
                                value={value1}
                                onChange={(event: any, newValue: Company | null) => {
                                    setValue1(newValue)
                                    
                                }}
                            />
                            <Button variant="contained" color="success" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
                                Agregar
                            </Button>

                            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                                <DialogTitle>Agregar Empresa</DialogTitle>
                                <DialogContent>
                                    <DialogContentText>Colocar Nombre de la Empresa a Agregar</DialogContentText>
                                    <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmitCompanyInfo}>
                                        <FormControl margin="normal">
                                            <TextField
                                                autoFocus
                                                margin="dense"
                                                name="label"
                                                label="Nombre de Empresa"
                                                type="text"
                                                fullWidth
                                                variant="standard"
                                                onChange={handleChangeAddCompanyInfo}
                                                value={addCompany?.label}
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                            />
                                            <TextField
                                                autoFocus
                                                margin="dense"
                                                name="location"
                                                label="Direccion de Empresa"
                                                type="text"
                                                fullWidth
                                                variant="standard"
                                                onChange={handleChangeAddCompanyInfo}
                                                value= {addCompany?.location}
                                                
                                            />
                                        </FormControl>
                                    </Box>
                                </DialogContent>
                                <DialogActions>
                                    <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                                    <Button type="submit">Agregar Tarea</Button>
                                </DialogActions>
                            </Dialog>
                        </Stack>
                    </FormControl>
                </Container>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
};

export default CreateUser; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

`setCompany` solo puede recibir un argumento `companies`:

```
//manejador de array empresas
const [company, setCompany] = useState(companies);
```

Pero al usar `spread operator` se esta intentando pasar multiples argumentos:

```
setCompany(...company, (setAddCompany({...addCompany, [name] : value})))
```

TS nos notifica lo siguiente:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter

Hay que declarar explicitamente que `company` es una copia del array en propagación (un solo argumento, un array):

```
setCompany([...company])
//setCompany([...company], (setAddCompany({...addCompany, [name] : value})))
```

Ahora bien, esto no creo que vaya a funcionar:

```
setCompany([...company], (setAddCompany({...addCompany, [name] : value})))
```

Porque la función `set` de `setState` regresa `undefined`:

```
setCompany([...company], (undefined))
```

Aún si se corrige la sintáxis, se esta pasando `undefined`:

```
setCompany([...company, (undefined)])
```

Además, primero se debe actualizar el valor del estado `addCompany` esperar el re-render y luego usar ese valor para actualizar `company`, de lo contrario se esta pasando el antiguo valor de `addCompany` a `company`.